# Representing white color in CIE L*a*b* to RGB conversion using opencv

Tags: c, opencv, rgb, color-space

I am using opencv for a certain image processing code. I need to extract the color layers from a certain picture. So what I do is keep the pixels having a certain value and set the remaining pixels to the background color (which is white in this case). For certain issues I have to carry out this entire operation in CIE-L*a*b* color space. The problem arises when I convert the above image to RGB, using `cvCvtColor()` the background no longer remains white. I have tried with different permutation and combination of values, but it either becomes red or blue or anything but not pure white.

I even made a picture in paint (just white) and converted it to L*a*b* space and printed the values in a text file. Here is the code

```
IplImage *image, *lab;
uchar *data;
FILE *fp;
int i, j;
image = cvLoadImage( "white.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
lab = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image->width,image->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
cvCvtColor(image, lab, CV_BGR2Lab);
data = (uchar*)lab->imageData;
fp= fopen("white.txt", "w");
for(i=0; i<lab->height; i++)
         for(j=0; j<lab->width; j++)
                  fprintf(fp, "L = %d, a = %d, b = %d\n", data[i*lab->widthStep + j*lab->nChannels +0], data[i*lab->widthStep + j*lab->nChannels +0], data[i*lab->widthStep + j*lab->nChannels +0]);
```

It shows all the three values to be 255. But when I set the pixel values in my required program to it, it becomes reddish.

Here is the code snippet to set the pixel value

```
image = cvLoadImage( "pic11.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
cvCvtColor(image, lab, CV_BGR2Lab);

copy = cvCreateImage(cvSize(lab->width,lab->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
cvCopy(lab, copy, NULL);
data2 = (uchar*)copy->imageData;    

copied = cvCreateImage(cvSize(copy->width,copy->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
data = (uchar*)copied->imageData;

for(i=x; i<copy->height; i++)
          for(j=y; j<copy->width; j++)
          {        
                   if(data2[i*copy->widthStep + j*copy->nChannels + 0] == r &&
                      data2[i*copy->widthStep + j*copy->nChannels + 1] == g &&
                      data2[i*copy->widthStep + j*copy->nChannels + 2] == b)
                   {
                           data[i*copy->widthStep + j*copy->nChannels + 0] = r;
                           data[i*copy->widthStep + j*copy->nChannels + 1] = g;
                           data[i*copy->widthStep + j*copy->nChannels + 2] = b;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       data[i*copy->widthStep + j*copy->nChannels + 0] = 255;
                       data[i*copy->widthStep + j*copy->nChannels + 1] = 255;
                       data[i*copy->widthStep + j*copy->nChannels + 2] = 255;
                   }
          }

copy_im = cvCreateImage(cvSize(copied->width,copied->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
cvCvtColor(copied, copy_im, CV_Lab2BGR);
cvSaveImage("copy.jpg", copy_im);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: At least as the numbers in L*a*b* are normally used, all three values being 255 doesn't even make sense. L normally only goes from 0 to 100. At least if memory serves, 100, 0, 0 should give pure white. Edit: a quick test shows that Photoshop (for one) seems to agree -- entering 100, 0, 0 for L, a, and b values gives RGB of 255, 255, 255.

Comment: CIELab white should be (100,0,0). Are you getting (255,255,255)? This is very wrong.

Comment: The reason I get 255 255 255 is because I guess the convert color function maps the L,a,b values to the range on 0-255. In general I know the values lie in '0≤L≤100, -127≤a≤127, -127≤b≤127'. But the convert color function maps it using 'L <- L*255/100, a <- a + 128, b <- b + 128'.

Comment: However with a little trial and error and searching it seems the following represents white in RGB. Atleast for me it`s working. L = 255, a = 128, b = 128.

Thanks Jerry and n.m !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up the comments roughly:

In L*a*b* The values are normally [0,100] and "a and "b" are signed, with no well defined boundaries.  In opencv for 8 bit images the values are converted as follows:

- L <- L * 255/100
- a <- a+128
- b <- b+128

In CIELab, "white" is represented roughly as (100,0,0) which becomes (255,128,128) by that transformation.  If you use 32-bit floating point images, then this last conversion is not needed and you can use (100.0,0.0,0.0) as white.